# Getting consistent dash count/length in matplotlib paths

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm using `matplotlib.patheffects` to draw a path using a dashed line.  My goal is to divide each path into exactly N segments spaced evenly along the path.  Since dashes need to be specified in pixel lengths and not in terms of data coordinates, I'm using `ax.transData.transform_point()`, and what I have works in most circumstances, but in cases where the figure needs to be scaled down, the dashes don't scale appropriately.

Here's a code sample that demonstrates the problem:

```py
import sys
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patheffects as PathEffects
from matplotlib.patches import PathPatch
from matplotlib.path import Path
import numpy as np

MIN=1 if len(sys.argv) <= 1 else int(sys.argv[1])
MAX=MIN if len(sys.argv) <=2  else int(sys.argv[2])
SCALE=4 if len(sys.argv) <=3  else int(sys.argv[3])
COUNT=MAX-MIN+1

fig = plt.figure(1, figsize=(COUNT*SCALE,SCALE))

for i in range(MIN, MAX+1):
    ax = plt.subplot(1, COUNT, i-MIN+1)
    ax.set_xlim(0, i)
    ax.set_ylim(0, i)
    path = Path([(0,0), (0,i) ,(i,i)], [Path.MOVETO, Path.CURVE3, Path.CURVE3])
    pp = PathPatch(path, fill=False)

    def path_length(path):
        QI_SAMPLES=1000
        v = path.vertices
        v = [ax.transData.transform_point(p) for p in v ]
        if len(v) > 2:
            v = [ quad_interpolate( i/(1.0 * QI_SAMPLES), v[0], v[1], v[2])
                  for i in range(0, QI_SAMPLES)]
        dv = np.diff(v, axis=0)
        return np.sum(np.sqrt(np.sum(dv**2, axis=-1)))

    def quad_interpolate(i, A, B, C):
        (ax, ay) = A
        (bx, by) = B
        (cx, cy) = C
        ii = 1.-i
        i2 = i*i
        ii2 = ii*ii
        rx = ax*ii2 + 2*bx*ii*i + cx*i2
        ry = ay*ii2 + 2*by*ii*i + cy*i2
        return (rx, ry)

    ax.add_patch(pp)

    length = path_length(path)
    dash_length = length/(2*i)
    space_length = length/(2*i)
    offset=-(space_length/2)

    pe = [PathEffects.withStroke(linewidth=3,
                                 dashes=[offset, (dash_length, space_length)],
                                 foreground="b")]
    pp.set_path_effects(pe)

plt.show()
```

The command line arguments are (minimum segments) (maximum segments) (subplot scale).  You might have to run it with different command-line arguments to trigger the problem depending on your display size -- on my system, running with "1 8 3" shows this:

[image: good plot]

while running with "1 8 4" shows this:

[image: bad plot]

As you can see, the second plot isn't quite right -- the eighth subplot only has seven dashes, and the others are a bit off as well.

How can I do this so that the dash lengths are reliably transformed to the coordinate space of the underlying axes regardless of scale?  Or is there some other way to get dashed lines along paths that doesn't rely on specifying them in pixel lengths?

**Update:**  Here's what things look like plotting a line instead of a curve.  Good:

[image: good plot 2]

Bad:

[image: bad plot 2]

As pointed out in comments, it appears even the "good" plots are slightly off since the subplots aren't quite square.  But isn't the `ax.transData.transform_point` transformation supposed to take care of this?

Comment: I couldn't get the code to run on my system. My first guess is that the transform is not correct. I was actually wondering if the "1 8 3" series is wrong as well. It seems as if the data is symmetric around the anti-diagonal, but then the blue line should be from y=0.4 to x=0.6, but it is shifted a bit to the origin. Making a simpler path (a straight line would be best) is the easiest way to check if the path length is calculated correctly.

Comment: I would also take the functions out of the for loop. It is definitely better style and who knows what kind of problems it gives.

Comment: @Robbert, what error do you get running it?  FWIW, Taking the functions out of the for loop doesn't change the result.

Comment: The final line is `TypeError: set_dashes() argument after ** must be a mapping, not list`. It is something back-end related, not your code. And it is still better style to take the functions out.

Comment: Yeah, I guess matplotlib changed how set_dashes works in recent versions to allow for the offset parameter that makes this whole thing work.  I'm using matplotlib 1.2.0 on my system, which takes the offset: list form.

Comment: I just tried your suggestion of a straight line with: `Path([(0,0),(i,i)], [Path.MOVETO, Path.LINETO])` and the results are similar, i.e. it plots the correct number of segments along the line until it has to rescale the subplots.

Comment: And for the straight line it is really correct for "1 8 3", or sort-of-close? I bet it is only _really_ correct when the subplots are a square. Have you tried to make the subplots wider than they are high?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26264/discussion-between-robbert-and-tonycpsu)